# changing data with respect to time and/or any action in MVC 5 and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want some data to be modified on the base of time. For example if some data remains in database for longer time its priority field should be changed and It should appear automatically in existing view page without refreshing.

Thank you!

Comment: u can use signal-R to achive that

Comment: Can signal-R be bind with time? I thought it is only used for chat/communication purpose? Can you send me some link.

Comment: This question is way too broad. Please consider asking something more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using JQuery AJAX

**Controller**
This is my controller, here I am passing current date and time as a model to the partial view

```
public PartialViewResult GetCurrentDateTime()
{
    return PartialView("UpdateDate",DateTime.Now);
}
```

**JQuery**

In JQuery using `window.setInterval` function, I have call the action in particular time interval. And bind the partial view result to the div

```
$(function () {
    window.setInterval(yourfunction, 1000);
    function yourfunction() {
        var name = $(this).find(".name").html();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetCurrentDateTime',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#updateContainer").html(result);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In every second the `GetCurrentDateTime` will get call and display the current date and time. Instead of passing date and time you can pass your model